# How to use time.Time() to control projectile fire rate

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use time.Time() to control the fire rate of my projectiles, but after putting in the time logic, my player can no longer shoot any projectiles at all. How can I make it so that my player only fires once every half a second or so?

The following is a workable example;

## main game module

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from Projectile import Projectiles
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

# Spawn player

player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

projectile_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False


# ----- Event Loop

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('d'):
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('w'):
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == ord('s'):
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                projectile = Projectiles(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, -5, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                projectile = Projectiles(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 5, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                projectile = Projectiles(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 0, -5)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                projectile = Projectiles(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 0, 5)

            try:
                if projectile:
                    if time.Time() - last_shot > player.fire_rate:
                        projectile_list.add(projectile)
                        last_shot = time.Time()

            except:
                pass

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('d'):
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('w'):
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == ord('s'):
                player.changespeed(0, -3)


# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    projectile_list.update()



    screen.fill(GREEN)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    projectile_list.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## player module

```
from constants import *
import pygame
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.fire_rate = 1

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

## projectile module

```
import pygame
from constants import *

class Projectiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, x_speed, y_speed):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 4])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.x_speed = x_speed
        self.y_speed = y_speed



    def update(self):

        self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed
```

constants module defines a few colours. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `try` with a bare `except` is an anti-pattern and should almost never be used, because it hides all errors in the `try` clause and makes the code hard to debug. I'd remove it and rearrange the event handling code.

When an arrow key gets pressed, only change the velocity vector depending on the key instead of creating new projectile instances. Then check again if any of the arrow keys were pressed and if the timer is finished, create a projectile instance and pass the current velocity vector.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


BULLET_IMG = pg.Surface((9, 9))
BULLET_IMG.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine2'))


class Projectile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, vel):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = BULLET_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(vel)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.vel)


def main():
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    projectiles = pg.sprite.Group()
    previous_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
    speed = 12
    vel = Vector2(speed, 0)

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Only change the velocity vector.
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    vel = Vector2(-speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    vel = Vector2(speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    vel = Vector2(0, -speed)
                elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    vel = Vector2(0, speed)
                # If an arrow keys was pressed, create a new projectile.
                if event.key in (pg.K_LEFT, pg.K_RIGHT, pg.K_UP, pg.K_DOWN):
                    current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
                    # We're ready to fire when 500 ms have passed.
                    if current_time - previous_time > 500:
                        previous_time = current_time
                        # Now create the projectile instance and pass
                        # the position and the velocity.
                        projectiles.add(Projectile(pg.mouse.get_pos(), vel))

        projectiles.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        projectiles.draw(screen)

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: I had the try block in because in my full game there was a few issues with the projectiles and changing rooms etc. but I will definitely work on rearranging that code. Thankyou again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, strictly speaking, the answer is that you have `time.Time()` in a `try` block, and it should be `time.time()` (all lowercase). This throws an exception, so any time `time.Time() - last_shot > player.fire_rate` is evaluated, the `try` block isn't run. This would have been more apparent if you had caught the exception and thrown an error message rather than just `pass`ing.

There likely are further issues, but a more in-depth analysis of your code is difficult, as I don't see you initializing `last_shot` anywhere, nor `player.fire_rate`. The "minimal complete example" standard isn't just for the answerers, but for the asker as well. Basic debugging in isolating the issue as much as possible.

As another note, your while loop appears to contain nothing but a for loop, making it redundant. If you're doing that to just have the program run through the loop over and over again until the appropriate time, then `time.sleep()` would be probably be a better way to do that.

Comment: Ah I completely forgot that it was in a `try` block, that would explain a few things. As for not initialising `last_shot` and `player.fire_rate`, what exactly do you mean by initialising them? I defined `player.fire_rate` in the player class and `last_shot` in the `if` statement, was there something more I had to do to initialise them? If so Im not aware of how to.

Comment: @Goose_ I missed the `fire_rate` definition. The `last_shot` is indeed defined in the the `if` statement, but it's evaluated in the condition, then defined in the block. So unless it's defined somewhere else first, you won't get to the part where it's defined, because you'll first have to evaluate `time.Time() - last_shot > player.fire_rate` before you get to where `last_shot` is defined.